# nfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage message not sent or accepted

Tags: android, nfc

I am building 2 NFC enabled apps, one is supposed to send a message and the other to receive it.

**Sending app Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.joyride.nfc_merchant">  
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NFC_Merchant">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Sending app Main Activity**

```
package com.joyride.nfc_merchant;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String message;
    NdefRecord ndefRecord;
    NdefMessage ndefMessage;
    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        message = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_message)).getText().toString();
        ndefRecord = NdefRecord.createTextRecord(null, message);
        ndefMessage = new NdefMessage(ndefRecord);
        nfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(ndefMessage, this);
    }
}
```

**Receiving app android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.joyride.nfc_customer">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NFC_Customer">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Receiving app Main Activity**

```
package com.joyride.nfc_customer;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        TextView messageView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageView);
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Parcelable[] rawMessages =
                    intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            if (rawMessages != null) {
                NdefMessage[] messages = new NdefMessage[rawMessages.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < rawMessages.length; i++) {
                    messageView.setText(((NdefMessage) rawMessages[i]).toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've installed each app on another phone. Off course the receiving app is not registering the message. Am I missing something here? How do I go about debugging this?

Comment: What Android versions of the 2 phones are you using?

Comment: Did you notice that your "sendMessage" method is connected to nothing ? "Sending" of an NDF-message is not possible but you can emulate a class 4 type tag - search for "HCE" = "Host based card emulation".

Comment: @MichaelFehr my understanding was that by calling nfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage, I'm 'queuing' the message to be picked up by the next NFC enabled divide that comes along. I didn't understand your second point. I'm not trying to do any encription.

Comment: You were asked by @Andrew what Android versions are running on your 2 phones because setNdefPushMessage was deprecated in API level 29. As a "replacement" you should use Bluetooth/Wifi for data transfer. If you still want to use NFC you need to run a dedicated "sender app" on the first and a "receiver app" on the second device. The sender app emulates a class 4 tag by using "HCE" = "Host based card emulation" and the reader app needs to know the specific AID ("application identifier") that was used to emulate the card on sender app - all in all there is a lot work to do to get this to run.

Comment: As @Michael Fehr says setNdefPushMessage was deprecated and removed from Android 10, so it is not a solution to use this going forward and might be the cause of why it not working for you if any one of the phones you are using is Android 10 or higher. Which is why I asked about the Android versions. HCE is an option but Bluetooth/Wifi is better

Comment: The customer app is running on android 11, and the merchant app on android 12. I don't want to use Bluetooth/WiFi because that doesn't fit a Point of sale use case, but I understand that the route I need to take is the HSC?